# Injecting class into a service

Tags: android, mvvm, service, kotlin, background

I'm developing an android app, and I'm using MVVM pattern with Dagger, Databinding, etc.

Currently I have a network layer called DataManager which injects in every ViewModel. This Datamanager class is the one who makes request to my server.

It look like this

```
   @Singleton
    class DataManager @Inject constructor(context: Context, private val sharedPreferences: ISharedPreferences, private val apiHelper: APIHelper) : IDataManager {
...
    }
```

Everything works fine with fragments/activies but now I want to start a service and make a request in the background but I'm not sure **how should inject my data manager class in the service.**

Service looks like:

```
class UploadService constructor() : BaseTaskService() {

    private lateinit var filePaths: ArrayList<String>
    private var sourceID: Int = 0
    private var typeID: Int = 0

...
onStartCommand ..
onBind ..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way as activities/fragments using `@ContributesAndroidInjector`

Your app module :

```
@Module(
    includes = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuilderModule::class, ServiceBuilderModule::class, ...]
)
abstract class ApplicationModule {
...
}
```

Your services subcomponents :

```
@Module
abstract class ServiceBuilderModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeUploadService(): UploadService
}
```

Then you can inject :

```
class UploadService : BaseTaskService() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dataManager: DataManager
    ...
}
```

Make sur your class `BaseTaskService` inherit from `DaggerService` or add `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` in its `onCreate` method